# Understanding the execution time of a memory access code with varying strides

Tags: performance, caching, optimization, cpu-architecture, powerpc

I was trying to understand the execution time of the following code for different steps but some figures are really confusing to me. This is a simple code for memory reads with increasing steps.
Here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=1024;
    int numLoop=a;
    int temp =0;
    int * arr;
    arr = (int*) malloc (100000000 * sizeof(int));

    for(int array=a; array<(a+1); array+=1) {
        for(int step=1; step<(numLoop+1); step*=2) {
            clock_t begin = clock();

            for(int v=1; v<(step+1); v++) {
                for(int i=0; i<array; i+=step) {  
                    temp = (temp+arr[i]) % 33721;
                }
            }

            clock_t end = clock();
            double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("%0.6lf %d %d\n",elapsed_secs,step,array);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got the following results after execution

```
0.000073 1 1024
0.000069 2 1024
0.000078 4 1024
0.000099 8 1024
0.000140 16 1024
0.000220 32 1024
0.000432 64 1024
0.000682 128 1024
0.001354 256 1024
0.002693 512 1024
0.005178 1024 1024
```

Architecture details:

Freescale p4080ds QorIQ processor
Numer of active core:1 (configured) 
L1 cache : 32kB
L2 cache : 128kB
L3 cache : 2MB 
(More about the architecture is [here](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/prod_brief/P4080PB.pdf))

Here the most disturbing thing for me is the last line of the result. When step=1024 then it is accessing arr[0] 1024 times which should be in the cache after first access. Then why does it take the highest execution time( 0.005178) of all?

Comment: Format this code so that people will take the time to read it.

Comment: In my humble opinion, trying to truly understand and predict the access time behavior of a PC architecture has become completely hopeless: you need to integrate three levels of cache, virtual memory, and concurrent machine activity. To deal with the related non-determinism, you need statistical observations.

Comment: It is not the best idea to perform a modulo in the memory access loop. It can introduce a significant overhead.

Comment: What's the purpose of your srand there? Even if you were randomizing something it should be called once at the beginning. Also - where do you initialize arr? Otherwise that's undefined behavior

Comment: What is the purpose of the modulo?  It only affects `temp`, which you're not referring to?

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is by reinserting the `srand()`, which you had in your original code, but edited out without updating your measurements or your question.  You were just timing the `srand()`.

Comment: I just deleted the srand. Yes, modulo only effects temp but it's true for all steps. Then why step=1024 takes more execution time than others?

Comment: @Peter, yes I just checked, after deleting srand the result changed significantly. So does it shows that I was just measuring the srand()? And I did the same experiment with write through cache and seeing the same behavior I mentioned above without srand()? Is it explainable? Thanks!

Comment: After I removed srand, I saw very small dependence on step.  If anything, it ran slightly longer for low step values.  I can't understand the questions in your comment.  If removing `srand()` changed the results significantly, why is your post still showing the old results?  We still can't reproduce what you're seeing, so I don't know what effect you're actually asking about.

Comment: @Peter, After removing srand() I execute the code on a powerpc which has write through caching policy. And I am seeing the same results as I mentioned in my post (i.e higher step takes higher execution time). Is it possible to explain this behavior with write-through caching?

Comment: There's probably something else going on.  Can't help you with what.

Comment: You need to account for many things like prefetching, size of memory pages, TLB cache, compiler optimizations among others. In order to help you you should provide details about your architecture (exact model), operative system, compiler and compilation flags.